# ¿Cómo hacer un Alert (javaScript) en PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Quiero que me salte un alert cuando entre en el `else`. He encontrado dos formas de hacer el alert.

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Error al crear sugerencia\");</script>";
```

o

```
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Error al crear sugerencia");</script>';
```

Pero no me hace el alert, se me imprime por consola

[image: Captura de la consola]

Os dejo el codigo PHP

```
$asunto = str_replace("'", "''", $asunto);
$comunicacion = str_replace("'", "''", $comunicacion);

echo $insertNoticia="insert into ib_noticia_interna (ID_NOTICIA_INTERNA,ASUNTO_NOTICIA,CREADOR,CUERPO_NOTICIA,fecha_inicio_vis,fecha_fin_vis,imagen) values(ID_NOTICIA_INTERNA.nextval,'$asunto','$selectorDep','$comunicacion','$fechaIni','$fechaFin','$url')";

$parseNoticia = oci_parse($intranetconn, $insertNoticia);

$execNoticia = oci_execute($parseNoticia);
if ($execNoticia) {
    createNotificacion($intranetconn,$asunto,$fechaIni,$fechaFin,$selectorDep,'comunicacion');
}else{

    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Error al crear sugerencia\");</script>";
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer un ALERT en php? ¿Por qué se me imprime por consola y a los demas les funciona?

Comment: Pero el alert que se te está mostrando es `Fotos guardadas`.

Comment: La captura esta realizada con `echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Fotos guardadas\");</script>";`

Comment: Prueba `echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; echo 'alert("Error al crear sugerencia")'; echo '</script>';` Me parece que tus errores son las comillas `""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado el error y lo notifico por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

Resulta que el PHP que estaba ejecutando, se llamaba mediante AJAX.

```
  <?php
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      dataType: "html",
      data: formData, 
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.
      success: function(data)
      {
      setTimeout(function(){

        //Añadimos el elemento <script> que genera /comunicaciones/insertarComunicado.php

        console.log("se ha escrito correctamente");
        console.log(data);
        navbackoffice('modules/backoffice/comunicaciones/gestion_comunicaciones.php');
      },2200);

     ?>
```

Resulta que al hacer `console.log(data)` todos los `echos`  y `returns` del php se muestran por console.log.

He puesto `$('body').append(data);` y añade el script que esta devolviendo el php.

Codigo correcto:

```
<?php
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      dataType: "html",
      data: formData, 
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.
      success: function(data)
      {
      setTimeout(function(){

        //Añadimos el elemento <script> que genera /comunicaciones/insertarComunicado.php
        $('body').append(data);
        console.log("se ha escrito correctamente");
        //console.log(data);
        navbackoffice('modules/backoffice/comunicaciones/gestion_comunicaciones.php');
      },2200);

  ?>
```

Comment: "_ todos los echos y returns del php se muestran por console.log_" no es correcto. En tu caso particular, haces `console.log(data)` y eso es lo que hace que los `echo` se muestren por consola (porque están mostrando el resultado por consola)